# Is spring-security SpringSecurityLdapTemplate still vulnerable to LDAP Entry Poisoning?

Tags: spring-security, ldap, spring-ldap

According to a paper by Alvaro Muñoz and Oleksandr Mirosh spring security, from version 3.2.0 onwards, is vulnerable to LDAP Entry Poisoning.

See:

- page 28 of https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-16/materials/us-16-Munoz-A-Journey-From-JNDI-LDAP-Manipulation-To-RCE-wp.pdf
- https://youtu.be/Y8a5nB-vy78?t=2111

Is this still an issue on the latest version of spring-security? If so, how could we solve this?

Kind regards
Carlos